# Missing value(s) in Pandas Dataframe index if value actually same as previous one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a simple Python script that reads a music database and applies a simple algorithm based on the track ratings to rank my album collection. I'm using Pandas for this and write the resulting dataframe to .xlsx for further analysis.

The dataframe has two indexes (Artist and Album) and then a single value column. My issue is that if the same artist appears in two or more consecutive rows, then the 2nd and subsequent index values are left blank by Pandas meaning I can't filter on the artist in Excel... see below - the 2nd "Bruce Springsteen" is missing from the Index:

```
                                                                                           piprating
Artist                                 Album                                                        
The Rolling Stones                     Let It Bleed                                        79.629608
Arlo Guthrie                           Alice's Restaurant                                  76.926501
Bruce Springsteen                      Born In The USA                                     76.584929
                                       The Wild, The Innocent & The E Street Shuffle       76.391921
Bob Dylan                              Blood On The Tracks                                 76.012009
Simon & Garfunkel                      Bridge Over Troubled Water                          74.660805
Van Morrison                           Astral Weeks                                        74.487892
The Rolling Stones                     Sticky Fingers                                      74.048929
Bruce Springsteen                      Nebraska                                            73.646199
```

Is there a way to get Pandas to complete this Index and not leave it blank? I guess this is probably trivial but it's stumped me...

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just reset the index. This would make all the blank values fill back in with the artist's name since they will no longer be grouped. Each row will get a sequential number as their index.

```
df.reset_index()
```

However, this means they won't be grouped. Any other processing you might want to do that relies on the dataframe being indexed by artist and album will now not be referencing the same index. But, you can always regroup the dataframe for that.

Comment: It has the added bonus of giving me the numeric index I wanted so that I can see what position each album is in the ranking (with a little numpy function to start the index at 1 instead of 0) :-)